# Error after page refresh - Error: Package subpath './yup/dist/yup' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, yup

I am using yup and react-hook-form for one of my modals, everything works, but when I refresh the page the app crashes and I see this error:

```
Error: Package subpath './yup/dist/yup' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/rips/Desktop/myapp-next rules/node_modules/@hookform/resolvers/package.json

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

these are my imports

```
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup/dist/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you tried `import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup"`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to downgrading the node version.

1. First install nvm from [here.](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
2. Then install 16.15.1 (current version is 18.5)
3. Then use nvm use 16.15.1 and then try to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade "@hookform/resolvers": "2.8.8"
It will fix the issue